# Serving HTML snapshot from alternative server when using #! and _escaped_fragment_

Tags: ajax, seo, google-crawlers

We currently are developing a set of (jquery)plugins to use our software from the sites of our clients. Our clients include these plugins in their pages, the plugins get their data from our API (on another server) and render the application in the client-page.

Within the plugins de user navigates through hash-changes. We really like to do some SEO for these urls.  Google provides a way to index ajax-enabled sites through providing HTML snapshots as alternative content: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification.

This is all very nice when serving the ajax-enabled application from your own server. But in our situations, the host-page is served on client.com, and our javascripts are served from include.oursystem.com. There plugins get their data through CORS-calls from api.oursystem.com. We have no access to the server of client.com.

Long story, short question: is there a way of serving the HTML snapshots from an alternative server we control, e.g. from api.oursystem.com? Or are there other alternative for indexing our application on the client pages?